# Nagios - "Unable to send check for host" or "run check for service"

Tags: nagios

I have Nagios core 4.2.4 installed on a CentOS 7 box to monitor my HP network switch. I want to start with the minimum so this is how I installed it:

```
yum -y install nagios nagios-plugins-all
```

In my /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg, I uncomment this

```
cfg_dir=/etc/nagios/switches
```

Then I created this "switches" folder and created "ABCDESH01-01.cfg" in it. It contains "define host" and "define service" for check_ping.

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               ABCDESW01-01
    service_description     PING
    check_command           check_ping!100.0,20%!200.0,60%
    normal_check_interval   5
    retry_check_interval    1
    }
```

Then I started the nagios serivce with "systemctl start nagios". Then I start seeing repeated error messages in /var/log/nagios/nagios.log

```
[1489462244] Unable to send check for host 'ABCDESW01-01' to worker (ret=-2)
[1489462424] Unable to run check for service 'PING' on host 'ABCDESW01-01'
```

I can manually ran the check_ping

```
# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H 10.0.3.131 -w 100.0,20% -c 200.0,60%
PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.88 ms|rta=0.881000ms;100.000000;200.000000;0.000000 pl=0%;20;60;0
```

I did not touch the command.cfg. It looks fine to me

## 'check_ping' command definition

```
define command{
    command_name    check_ping
    command_line    $USER1$/check_ping -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p 5
    }
```

What does the two "unable" errors mean and how do I fix them?

Does the nagios tracks the result in the /var/spool/nagios/status.dat file? Right now for the "servicestatus" it is all 0

```
servicestatus {
    ...
    has_been_checked=0
    check_latency=0.000
    current_state=0
    ...
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does the host definition look like?

Comment: I also tried to change the username and password to be root to run the nagios service in /usr/lib/systemd/system/nagios.service but still seeing the same error...

Comment: @NagiosSupport thanks for your response. Which host file are you talking about? In my /etc/nagios directory I can't find anything called "host"... Are you talking about the system /etc/hosts file? I only have localhost in it. Thanks

Comment: @NagiosSupport so I set the setenforce = 0 and it works now! Any recommendation with what I should do to not having to disable SELinux? Thanks

Comment: I meant the host file for the host definition. The services need to be attached to an object called a 'host' in nagios-speak. As far as disabling SELinux goes, we do not officially support any policies - but having said that, I've seen quite a few out in the wild so it is possible. Maybe you could run at permissive?

Comment: @NagiosSupport I don't know exactly what SELinux does and I don't have problem running it in "permissive" mode. Thank you for your help! I will have more when I play with it more.

Comment: Whoa! Pump those brakes! I would take the time to get up to speed on SELinux first. It is a very powerful tool, and you should learn how to wield it carefully before you decide you don't need it (IMO). Here is a great starter tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-selinux-on-centos-7-part-1-basic-concepts

Comment: Thank you for the link @nagiossupport. My role is to learn how to use your application to monitor my network equipment. I am from the networking back ground by the way. Once I got the config figured out I will hand it to the system admin to properly deploy them. I am sure that they won't simply disable selinux :)

Answer (score 2):

With NagiosSupport's help, we found out that it was SELinux that was in the "enforcing" mode that was causing the issues. Once set it to "permissive" by running shell command setenforce=0, everything works fine now.

Comment: No, a bad policy is causing the issues, not selinux.  The policy was apparently not updated in the EPEL package when updating to nagios-4.3.2.

Comment: Moved to a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set just the nagios selinux contexts to permissive mode like this:

```
# semanage permissive -a nagios_t
# semanage permissive -a nagios_script_t   # for cgi
# semanage permissive -a nagios_admin_t  # if you have selinux trouble with admin
```

No sense completely disabling selinux.